# Error Configuring Workflow Manager

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I upgraded workflow manager to 1.0 Refresh but now I can't get it to configure, I get the following error:

> VERBOSE: [03/04/2014 11:09:30]: Validating input and configuration
>   parameters. VERBOSE: [03/04/2014 11:09:33]: Installing auto-generated
>   certificate. VERBOSE: [03/04/2014 11:09:36]: Granting 'Log on as
>   Service' privilege to the RunAs account. VERBOSE: [03/04/2014
>   11:09:36]: Workflow Manager configuration starting. VERBOSE:
>   [03/04/2014 11:09:39]: Configuring Workflow Manager runtime settings.
>   Add-WFHost : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>   The api-version in the query string is not supported. Either remove it
>   from the Uri or use one of
>   '2012-03'..TrackingId:732238ff-9715-4761-acc6-d68ec94e0faf_GS
>   HP2013,TimeStamp:03/04/2014 10:09:40 At line:1 char:1
>   + Add-WFHost -WFFarmDBConnectionString 'Data Source=SHP2013\SHAREPOINT;Initial Cat ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Add-WFHost], ArgumentExce    ption
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WFRuntimeSettingFailed,Microsoft.Workflow.Deploy
>   ment.Commands.AddWFHost

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Service bus 1.0 CU must be installed: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2799752